# SP2013 - Display People Picker in Custom Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, peoplepicker

I'm currently trying to do this. I have a Website that gets put together pretty customly from many infos from list items and I won't be able to use the standard list-Webparts provided with SharePoint. Now there will be one Column where I want to display Users as in the lists

Is it possible to create a the field like it would appear in a normal list-Webpart including current availability status etc. without having to rebuild it comepletely from scratch?

Would be great if someone had an idea. Thanks in advance and

Greetings Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use JavaScript and the SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager API. You might also be interested in https://splyncpresence.codeplex.com/

Comment: That's looking really promising. I'll take a closer a look at that and will probaby mark this as an answer afterwards. Thanks alot

Comment: a litte addition maybe. I had a little problem using the LoginName from my SharePoint-Site. If you encounter the same problem try

encodeURIComponent(LoginName)

I just added it to the jQuery.lyncpresence.js file, so it'll automatically do that by just adding

accountName = encodeURIComponent(accountName);

after line2

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column in your list and choose the type as "People or Group". That would work.

Comment: Thanks but thats not really what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1. user SIP
2. [lyncpresence.js](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=splyncpresence)
3. [optional] add  `accountName = encodeURIComponent(accountName);` **in lyncpresence.js** after line2

and use it like it described on [link](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=splyncpresence) above.
Example:

```
var settings = {type: "default", redirectToProfile: true};
AccountName is 'DomainNam\\\UserName' OR 'i:0%23.f|membership|username' (you can get it on your_site/_api/web/siteusers  in 'LoginName' field)
selector.createpresence('AccountName', settings);
```

It will return in your selector user presence html.

Comment: Its not an answer to topic. Just explain how to render your own user presence html.